# AngularJS - Change multiple CSS classes on 1 <div> from multiple options

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-class

I'm afraid I'm new to Angular and therefore my knowledge is limited. I'm hoping there is an easy solution to this and I'd very grateful for any help.

Problem: I have multiple dropdown lists all populated with data from a $scope.list and when one of the lists is clicked, it updates the variables $scope.current. I'm hoping to use the $scope.current array data in a container class elsewhere.

Code:

// ANGULAR

```
Set the current item
$scope.current = {
    'activeClass1': 'initial-class1',
    'activeClass2': 'initial-class2'
};

Populate the lists
$scope.itemsList1 = [
    {'name': 'foo1'},
    {'name': 'foo2'},
    {'name': 'foo3'}
];

$scope.itemsList2 = [
    {'name': 'bar1'},
    {'name': 'bar2'},
    {'name': 'bar3'}
];
```

HTML LIST 1

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
   <li ng-repeat="item in itemList1">
     <a href="#" ng-click="current.activeClass1=item.name;>{{item.name}}</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

HTML LIST 2

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
   <li ng-repeat="item in itemList2">
     <a href="#" ng-click="current.activeClass2=item.name;>{{item.name}}</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

// HTML TO UPDATE WHEN ABOVE LISTS ARE CLICKED

```
<div class="container" ng-class="{{current.activeClass1}} {{current.activeClass2}}">
    Note: two classes need to be added to the parent and kept updated 
</div>
```

// OUTPUT
    Only initial 'container' class present.

// UPDATE
Thanks to the answers given, the jsFiddle showed that it should be working, but my problem was that `ng-view` was causing problems with my `$scope` - as soon as separated those dynamic classes and the ng-view, everything worked. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two extra closing curly braces in your code. this works: http://jsfiddle.net/s7AK7/

```
$scope.current = {
    'activeClass1': 'initialClass',
    'activeClass2': 'initialClass'
};

$scope.itemsList1 = [
    {'name': 'item1'},
    {'name': 'item2'},
    {'name': 'item3'}
];

$scope.itemsList2 = [
    {'name': 'item1'},
    {'name': 'item2'},
    {'name': 'item3'}
];
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm not sure why your jsFiddle is working, but my real-world code isn't. Hmm. I'm sure I'll figure it out and give you the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing:

```
ng-class="[current.activeClass1, current.activeClass2]"
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. This adds the classes initially, but if the lists are clicked and updated, the classes on the container don't get updated.